# How to apend value to vertex property use only gremlin api

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I got a graph with vertexes, and i need to update vertex property
by writing some string to the end of old value (append value to the end of old property)

Also i need to do it only by gemlin api?

I need to use only api, cause i send my query another server, where it will be execute

So, for example, if my question would be "set value if it does not present" - i know how to do that

```
traversal.coalesce(__.has(key), __.property(key, value));
```

But in my case, i cant use something like this:

```
Optional<? extends Property<Object>> property = traversal.properties(key).tryNext();
if (property.isPresent()) {
    Object oldValue = property.get().value();
    if (oldValue instanceof String && value instanceof String) {
        traversal.property(key, oldValue .toString() + value.toString());
    }
} else {
    traversal.property(key, value);
}
```

cause i must to send my query and only after that it will be executed

i try to do something like that:

```
traversal.coalesce(__.has(key).property(value, __.properties(key).next().value() + value),
__.property(key, value));
```

But of caurse it is something crazy, and also i cant check, if value is a String before append new value, in suth a case

How can i solve my question?

Answer (score 1):

Gremlin does not yet have string manipulation functions, so it is not possible to do this in Gremlin without use of lambdas:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').sideEffect{it.get().property('name', it.get().value('name') + 'a')}
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko')
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','markoa')
==>v[1]
```

The above example utilizes TinkerGraph, but depending on the graph database you are using you may see slightly different behavior and might need to write the lambda in a different way to get the same result (e.g. i don't think that approach would work with DS Graph because  I don't think that you can call the `property(key,value)` method on a `Vertex` object with that implementation).

Obviously, you also have the option to do this mutation in two separate traversals:

```
gremlin> oldVal = g.V().has('person','name','marko').values('name').next()
==>marko
gremlin> oldVal = g.V().has('person','name','marko').property('name',oldVal + 'a')
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko')
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','markoa')
==>v[1]
```

Hopefully, `String` manipulation functions as well as other type specific operations like `Date` functions will be made available in future releases. Some of that discussion is happening on [TINKERPOP-2334](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2334).

Comment: Groovy expression is failing: `g.V().sideEffect{it.get().property("def", it.get().value("abc"))} `. Error: " Gremlin query syntax error: Unsupported groovy language rule: 'closure' text: '{it.get().property("def",it.get().value("abc"))}' @ line 1, column 55. 1 Error(s) ".

Comment: what graph database are you using?

Comment: I'm using cosmos DB.

Comment: as I mentioned in the answer whether you can take this approach or not is dependent on your graph. CosmosDb won't support lambdas. in your case you look like you are just assigning one property value to another in which case, you don't need a lambda. CosmosDB might support: `g.V().property('def',values('abc'))`

Comment: I've already tried it, it gives: ``` Error: Cannot create ValueField on non-primitive type GraphTraversal.```

Comment: I'm not sure how you can accomplish it then. CosmosDB supports most Gremlin language syntax but there are yet features it needs to implement.  You would have to try to get your question answered by CosmosDB experts.